# Month and day names come out garbled when setting custom formatting expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

My dataset has a `Datetime` field called `FilmReleaseDate`.If I set textbox properties to format the date with one of the stock Date formats it works fine. But if I choose custom and enter an expression I get garbage back.

For example, the date's actual value will be `12/15/2005` and if I just want to display the month so that what is output is "December" I use the following expression for a custom format: `=MonthName(Month(Fields!FilmReleaseDate.Value))`

What displays on the report is `Dece0ber`.

I've also tried it with the optional boolean parameter:
`=MonthName(Month(Fields!FilmReleaseDate.Value), false)`

But the result is the same.

Similarly when attempting to display just the day of the week.

Same value `12/15/2005`.

The expression: `=WeekdayName(Weekday(Fields!FilmReleaseDate.Value,0),false,0)`

But what's output is: `T12ur015a5`

Not sure what's happening.

EDIT --

Using the same expressions to create a calculated field everything displays correctly. It only occurs if the expression is used in the Custom format window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific formats/rules that can go in that Custom format box, similar to Excel and such. When you put your expression in there, it evaluated the expression to `December`, then converted `December` into a format template, and applied that template to 12/15/2005. All of that together ended up producing `Dece0ber`.

A couple of options to get what you want:

1. Simply place that expression as the value of the text box (which from your edit it seems you have achieved similar results by using a calculated field).
2. Use the correct custom format which results in the month name being returned. In this case, what you would enter in the Custom format box is `MMMM` (case sensitive). I believe [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx) gives a rundown on what the possibilities are for custom formats. The section specifically for the month name is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mmmm-custom-format-specifier).

Using the first link, we can figure out how we got `Dece0ber` in the first place. There are no date/time formats for the characters D, e, c, b, or r, so those were displayed exactly as they were. There is a format for "m", which is the minute of the datetime. I assume your `FilmReleaseDate` field is just a date, so the minute was 0. Hence `Dece0ber`.

Similarly for the weekday, it looks like 12/15/2005 was a Thursday. So the custom format string was "Thursday". There is no date/time format for the characters T, u, r, and a. "h" is hour (1-12), and if `FilmReleaseDate` is just a date then the time is midnight, so the hour would be 12. "s" is second, and again the second would be 0 for a date. "d" is day, so we see the 15 there. And "y" is a one or two digit year with no leading zero, so there is the 5 on the end for 2005. Put it together and we get `T12ur015a5`.